# Validate Int Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to figure out how to ensure that a user enters an int into a text field with JavaScript. Currently, I have the following:

```
var myVal = $("#myField").val();
if (isInt(myVal)) {
  alert("Awesome!");
} else {
 alert("No Good");
}

function isInt(i) {
    if ((i != null) && (i != undefined) && (i.length > 0)) {
        alert(typeof i);
        return (typeof i == 'number' && /^-?\d+$/.test(i + ''));
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I enter 123 into the text field, I have noticed that the `typeof i` is "string". I'm not sure how to perform this kind of validation. Can someone please let me know? I was suprised I didn't have any success when I Googled this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
​function isInt(myVal) {
    return /^[+-]?\d+$/.test(myVal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `!isNaN(+myVal)` or `!isNaN(parseInt(myVal, 10))`

Comment: You can always use `parseInt` if you don't like using the unary `+` to convert it to a number :)

Comment: Also `myVal == ~~myVal` should work for integers up to 31 bits or so (maybe it's 32; I can't remember).

Comment: Depends on what the user needs. If being able to convert it to a number is enough then it is correct.

Comment: `"Validate Int Value in JavaScript"` the title of the question. There was nothing mentioned about conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short and sweet way

```
function isInt(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: That will also accept hex numbers. Use `parseInt(myVal, 10)` instead. Oh, and since when are zero and negative numbers not numbers? :p

Answer (score 0):

If you use the modulus operator on a non-integer number or string,

either a remainder or NaN is returned.

```
function isInt(i) {
   return i%1===0;
}
```